# ffmpeg: joining videos leads to "time skips" during playback

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I hope that someone can help me. I have the following two videos:

```
$ ffprobe 0.ts
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20170109
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-netcdf --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '0.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:09.28, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 51640 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 259 kb/s
```

and

```
$ ffprobe 1.ts
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20170109
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-netcdf --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:20.16, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 51163 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 266 kb/s
```

I merge the video and audio together with the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 'concat:0.ts|1.ts' -c copy 01.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20170109
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-netcdf --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:0.ts|1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:20.16, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 74933 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 259 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to '01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160, q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 259 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x56259655e560] DTS 157860 < 958161 out of order
frame=  869 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  170955kB time=00:00:38.37 bitrate=36491.6kbits/s speed= 178x    
video:170015kB audio:934kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.003137%
```

The result seems to play smoothly in mpv. However I noticed that the playback time "jumps" to 19 seconds when it reaches 9 seconds. If I play 01.mp4 in vlc the playback freezes at 9 seconds and continues at 19 seconds after a while. Here is the ffprobe-output for 01.mp4:

```
$ ffprobe 01.mp4
ffprobe version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20170109
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-netcdf --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:00:38.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 36471 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160, 36419 kb/s, 22.72 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can prevent this? I also tried to create 01.mp4 without using `-c copy` but the resulting video freezes at 9 seconds even in mpv (whereas it didn't freeze in mpv before). In any case leaving out `-c copy` seems to ignore the orientations of the videos. I need to concatenate videos with different orientation (some are horizontal and others are vertical). This is not a problem with `-c copy` but without it all videos get the vertical orientation and the horizontal ones are horizontally "squeezed" and vertically stretched, which destroys the video quality. I wouldn't mind to leave out `-c copy` if there was a way to tell concat to respect the individual orientation of each video file.

Thanks!

Comment: What does ffplay do?

Comment: Try with the [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1).

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating pts values when merging two videos like so:

`ffmpeg -i 'concat:0.ts|1.ts' -c copy -fflags +genpts output.mp4`

Comment: @user351041, you ever get this to work?